# Post one text field to multiple pages in php

Tags: php, html

I have one text field. How to post it to multiple pages like that

```
<form name="input1" action="frame.php" method="post">

<input type="date" name="T1"  size="18" value = "<?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>" >

<button name="B1" type="submit">

</form>

<form name="input2" action="frame2.php" method="post">

<button name="B2" type="submit">

</form>
```

How to post this date to both of these forms?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The only way would be to use JavaScript to mirror the value to another field in the second form and then use AJAX to submit both (You can only submit only one form at a time with "normal" HTTP).